# TypeError in read_parquet Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

I have a parquet file called `data.parquet`. I'm using the library `dask` from Python. When I run the line

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet('data.parquet',engine='pyarrow')
```

I get the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-807fa43763c1> in <module>
----> 1 df = dd.read_parquet('data.parquet',engine='pyarrow')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, infer_divisions)
   1395         categories=categories,
   1396         index=index,
-> 1397         infer_divisions=infer_divisions,
   1398     )
   1399 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py in _read_pyarrow(fs, fs_token, paths, columns, filters, categories, index, infer_divisions)
    858     _open = lambda fn: pq.ParquetFile(fs.open(fn, mode="rb"))
    859     for piece in dataset.pieces:
--> 860         pf = piece.get_metadata(_open)
    861         # non_empty_pieces.append(piece)
    862         if pf.num_row_groups > 0:

TypeError: get_metadata() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I just don't understand why this happens, since this is how it is implemented [here](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html).

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of pyarrow and dask are you using? Please update to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I resolved by upgrade version dask `2.30.0`